# Using internationalization in javascript

Tags: spring

I am creating an allpication using spring and hibernate framework. My application supports two languages 'English' and 'French'.
Whenever user fills a form and submit it, requesting is done using ajax. if any error occurs then a json is sent to client. My problem is that how can i use 
tag in javascript. my ajax function is :

```
function doAjaxPost() {
    // get the form values
    var userName = $('#userName').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.htm",
        data: "userName=" + userName + "&password=" + password,
        success: function(response){
            // we have the response
            if(response.status == null){
                 errorInfo = "";
                 for(i =0 ; i < response.result.length ; i++){
                     errorInfo += response.result[i].code + "</br>";
                 }
                 $("#loginErrors").html(errorInfo);
                 showErrors();
             }
         },
         error: function(e){
             alert('Error: ' + e);
         }
    });
}
```

In errorInfo only error code is written but how can i translate this error code from my properties file.

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

If you have your property files loaded into a [MessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource), you can use the [spring:message tag](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/tag/MessageTag.html) to get translations of all your codes.

Note, you will need to have a LocaleResolver or a LocaleChangeInterceptor configured for this to work.